# Why does the OpenCV BOW cluster function run very slow? How to improve its performance?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV BOW to train a SVM classifier, but when I calculate the vocabulary with

```
vocabulary = bowTrainer.cluster();
```

It has run 15 hours and is still running :-(

In my case, the bowTrainer may contain over 100 thousands descriptors, which may not be reduced.

The program is running with 4 threads on a Macbook Pro with 8GB memory and a 2.4G Dual-Core i5 CPU. It consumes 4GB memory and 98% CPU capacity.

Based on this background, how long would the cluster function take? Should I continue waiting?

And how can I improve the performance of cluster function and the training process?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should reduce the size of positive samples.